# Access nuxt.js env variable in feathers client plugin in production mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu-16.04, feathersjs, nuxt.js

I can't seem to access the `process.env.baseUrl` variable from the feathers client plugin. The variable returns an empty string. I can use the variable on server side. I can resolve it by hardcoding the url in `env.baseUrl` in *nuxt.config.js*, but I'd rather not. The weird thing is that it runs without any issues on a windows 10 machine in both *prod* and *dev* mode. However on Ubuntu vm in the Google Cloud it doesn't work. It also doesn't work when running from a docker container. Please advice. Am I missing something obvious?

### Configuration

system

```
Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Node 9.4.0
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "description": "",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "src",
  "keywords": [
    "feathers"
  ],
  "contributors": [],
  "bugs": {},
  "directories": {
    "lib": "src",
    "test": "test/"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "^8.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "cross-env HOST=localhost PORT=3000 BASE_URL=http://localhost:3000 DEBUG=@feathersjs* nodemon --watch src/ --watch config/ src/index.js",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "cross-env HOST=0.0.0.0 PORT=8080 NODE_ENV=production BASE_URL=https://example.com node src/index.js",
    "test": "mocha test/services/",
    "dev-debug": "node --inspect node_modules/.bin/nuxt"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@feathersjs/authentication": "^2.1.1",
    "@feathersjs/authentication-jwt": "^1.0.2",
    "@feathersjs/authentication-local": "^1.1.0",
    "@feathersjs/client": "^3.4.0",
    "@feathersjs/configuration": "^1.0.2",
    "@feathersjs/errors": "^3.2.2",
    "@feathersjs/express": "^1.2.0",
    "@feathersjs/feathers": "^3.1.1",
    "@feathersjs/socketio": "^3.2.0",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.0.1",
    "@nuxtjs/font-awesome": "^1.0.3",
    "@nuxtjs/pwa": "^2.0.5",
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.1",
    "buefy": "^0.6.3",
    "compression": "^1.7.1",
    "cookie-storage": "^3.1.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "feathers-authentication-management": "^2.0.0",
    "feathers-mongodb": "^2.9.1",
    "feathers-stripe": "^0.4.1",
    "feathers-vuex": "^1.1.4",
    "helmet": "^3.10.0",
    "izitoast": "^1.2.0",
    "mongodb": "^3.0.2",
    "node-ses": "^2.1.0",
    "nuxt": "^1.4.0",
    "nuxt-stripe-module": "^2.0.0",
    "pug": "^2.0.0-rc.4",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.4.5",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.0.4",
    "vee-validate": "^2.0.5",
    "vue-bulma-rating": "^1.0.1",
    "vue-no-ssr": "^0.2.2",
    "vue-notifications": "^0.9.0",
    "vue-observe-visibility": "^0.3.1",
    "vue-smoothscroll": "^0.1.1",
    "vue-social-sharing": "^2.3.3",
    "vue-stripe-elements": "^0.2.3",
    "vue2-animate": "^1.0.4",
    "winston": "^2.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.1.3",
    "eslint": "^4.17.0",
    "mocha": "^4.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "nodemon": "^1.14.12",
    "request": "^2.83.0",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6"
  }
}
```

feathers.js

```
import feathers from '@feathersjs/client'
import io from 'socket.io-client'
import { CookieStorage } from 'cookie-storage'

console.log('logging in the client')
console.log(process.env.baseUrl)

const socket = io(process.env.baseUrl)


const feathersClient = feathers()
  .configure(feathers.socketio(socket))
  .configure(feathers.authentication({ storage: new CookieStorage() }))

export default feathersClient
```

nuxt.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  /*
  ** Headers of the page
  */
  head: {
  },
  loading: false,
  loadingIndicator: 'circle',
  plugins: [
    {src: '~plugins/buefy'},
    { src: '~/plugins/vue-observe-visibility' },
    { src: '~/plugins/feathers' },
  ],
  manifest: {
    theme_color: '#3B8070'
  },
  /*
  ** Modules
  */
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/pwa'
  ],
  rootDir: path.resolve(__dirname),
  srcDir: path.resolve(__dirname, 'client'),
  dev: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
  build: {
    vendor: [
      '@feathersjs/client',
      'socket.io-client',
    ],
    postcss: {
      plugins: {
        'postcss-custom-properties': false
      }
    }
  },
  env: {
    baseUrl: process.env.BASE_URL
  }
}
```

Comment: You should retry to set your env vars with "cross-env" npm lib to be OS agnostic: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env

Comment: Thanks for you comment. The environment variable gets set and I can use it in the server side app. Just not on the client side as the nuxt.js docs promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because of your `build` and `prestart` stage. When you have below `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "cross-env HOST=localhost PORT=3000 BASE_URL=http://localhost:3000 DEBUG=@feathersjs* nodemon --watch src/ --watch config/ src/index.js",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "cross-env HOST=0.0.0.0 PORT=8080 NODE_ENV=production BASE_URL=https://example.com node src/index.js",
    "test": "mocha test/services/",
    "dev-debug": "node --inspect node_modules/.bin/nuxt"
  },
```

The `build` and `prestart` are run as independent commands and they will not see the `HOST=0.0.0.0 PORT=8080 NODE_ENV=production` envs. So you should either do it like below

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "cross-env HOST=localhost PORT=3000 BASE_URL=http://localhost:3000 DEBUG=@feathersjs* nodemon --watch src/ --watch config/ src/index.js",
    "prestart": "cross-env HOST=0.0.0.0 PORT=8080 NODE_ENV=production BASE_URL=https://example.com npm run build",
    "start": "cross-env HOST=0.0.0.0 PORT=8080 NODE_ENV=production BASE_URL=https://example.com node src/index.js",
    "test": "mocha test/services/",
    "dev-debug": "node --inspect node_modules/.bin/nuxt"
  },
```

Or use `npm-run-all`

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with nuxt.js. It has to do with that regardless of cross-env the environment variables from package.json do not get set. The only option is to export the environment variables from the shell in Ubuntu itself. The app works as designed.

Comment: How were you running it earlier? not using `npm start`?

Comment: I was, but the environment variables still didn't get reflected. I ran a test to confirm that that's the case. So the problem lies somewhere else.That's in line with this thread https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1707. Being a windows user however, the solution was too cryptic for me.

Comment: Please check the answer I posted